# ¿Como hacer para que con fadeOut el div no desaparezca?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, web

Buenas,mi problema es que cuando la palabra hola desaparece mundo pasa a ocupar el lugar de hola.
¿Se borra el div al usar fadeOut?
¿Como hacer para que esto no suceda?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <style>
    
    #caja{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    #caja2{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#caja").hide()
        .text("¡Hola")
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000);
    },2000);
       

    setTimeout(function(){
     $("#caja2").hide()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .text("Mundo!")
        .fadeOut(2000);
    },4000);     
    })
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="caja">
    </div>
    <div id="caja2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidentemente, al usar **[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)** se aplica la propiedad `display:none` a tu elemento, borrándolo visualmente del **[DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)**, lo que puedes hacer es animar la propiedad `opacity` del elemento haciendo que visualmente desaparezca pero que realmente continúe en su lugar:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#caja").hide()
    .text("¡Hola")
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .animate({
      'opacity': 0
    }, 2000);
},2000);


setTimeout(function(){
   $("#caja2").hide()
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .text("Mundo!")
      .animate({
        'opacity': 0
      }, 2000);
  },4000);     
})
```

```css
#caja{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}
#caja2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="caja">
</div>
<div id="caja2">
</div>
```